# How did I do this? - File content removed!

Tags: command-line

first of all, thank you for your contribute to this forum! I switched to ubuntu a few months ago for working reasons and these pages are a great help!

Now, getting to the point:
I was trying to count a specific pattern in a text file:
grep -c [pattern] [filename]
Now: the pattern was: 'greater than' sign, i.e.:  >
thus the command I gave was: grep -c > [filename]
I got this message: 
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

But now the text file was empty! (fortunately I had a backup...).
Why? Did I mess up in some previous operation or was it the last command I gave? I am just trying to make sense of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is technically accurate, but I think is circumventing the user's overall knowledge of what they were trying to do.  Let's focus on what you did wrong, and then rewrite the command so you can actually find the entries of ">" in the file instead.

(Explanation of why the file got dumped)
If you use > at the end of a line (try "ls > directory.txt") you'll wipe out directory.txt [if it exists], and input the results of the command.  If you use >>, it simply appends (adds to the end) of any existing file.  "grep" didn't realize you were actually searching for ">" instead of wanting to pipe the output into the file you intended to search.  As a result, it simply dumped nothing into the file you had data in.

In your case, you probably wanted to use this instead:

```
grep -c -- '>' filename.ext
```

Let us know if that fixes your problem!

Comment: The end of options `--` does not make any difference here. The sole character `>` is not an argument to `grep`, it's interpreted by the shell. By putting it between quotes it will become one, but then there's no reason to do it with `--`.

Comment: You missed the point of his question.  He was intending to (literally) search for a greater than symbol within the file.  I'm just designating end of options as habit.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! I didn't expect my question to be answered to so quickly :)

I created a test file and tried both the 'wrong' command and the right one, I know something more now...
Fortunately I had a backup for that 'vewy vewy impowtant' file...
Have a nice day
Max

Comment: To gertvdijk's point - the correct (and non-confusing) syntax would be "grep -c '>' filename.ext"   I habitually use "--" whenever I want to clearly designate I'm no longer specifying options to a program.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at [output redirection (Bash)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). By redirecting the regular output 'stdout' to `filename`, you're overwriting it. Error output, 'stderr' is still shown (in your terminal by default), though. That was the help text you saw.

To actually use the `>` character in grep as a character to match on, **escape** it in your shell (Bash), e.g.

```
grep -c \> myfile
```

Putting it between quotes, `'>'` will also work.

A snippet from the above link explains redirection more generally:

```
COMMAND_OUTPUT >
  # Redirect stdout to a file.
  # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it.

  ls -lR > dir-tree.list
  # Creates a file containing a listing of the directory tree.
[..]
1>filename
  # Redirect stdout to file "filename."
1>>filename
  # Redirect and append stdout to file "filename."
2>filename
  # Redirect stderr to file "filename."
2>>filename
  # Redirect and append stderr to file "filename."
&>filename
  # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks, it makes sense now. Next time I will select some other character to count... :(
Is there a way to count those special characters (like putting them within quotes or similar)?
Max

Comment: See my answer above to how to search for greater-than symbols.